# Connect Flask Restless API to Admin-on-rest (React)

Tags: python, rest, reactjs, flask-restless, admin-on-rest

I'm learnig flask and react to create a rest API (whit flask) and a rest client (whit react, Admin-on-Rest). I have create the Rest API whit Flask Restless.

I'm searching for some advices to connect the API to the client, but can't found what I need, if you know some way or have some tricks please tell me, it will be very helpfful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to now write a Rest client to make requests using Fetch

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Writing a rest client is very well documented in the aor docs. You will have to write a custom client or tweak your API to respond to requests of the format of one of the existing developer Rest Client libraries available with aor.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds as [Including admin-on-rest on another React app](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html)

good luck!

Comment: I need to to connect the flask api to the admi on rest, not two react apps